# How to re-write the link, with ".htaccess", with 2 parameters?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I I have this website, with this structure: `http://example.com/dir/index.php?first=12&second=16`. Now, I want to edit this link to: `http://example.com/dir/12/16`.

---

So, I put an `.htaccess` in `http://example.com/dir/`; there is content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ ?first=(\d+)&second=(\d+)
```

I have used this simple PHP for checking, which is placed at `http://example.com/dir/`:

```
<?php

/* ... */

echo $_GET['first'] . ' - ' . $_GET['second'];

/* ... */

?>
```

When I go to `http://example.com/dir/1/2`, it returns: `404`. So, my `.htaccess` does not work well as I want.

---

What is wrong with my `.htaccess`?

Comment: You only have 1 capture group and your path is `search.php?month=12&day=16`, not all numbers.

Comment: you only have 1 capture group so how do you get 2 variables?

Comment: Maybe `search\.php\?month=(\d+)&day=(\d+)`. Whats your error message?

Comment: That's not an error message or description of what happens.

Comment: Oh I thought you were loading `http://example.com/dir/index.php?first=12&second=16`, that doesn't make sense though thinking of it now.. Got an answer below now though that looks like it'd work.

Comment: @YeuSeChia You keep changing your structure in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this `.htaccess` in `http://example.com/dir/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ ?first=$1&second=$2
```

It is simple.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 2 capture gropus for your RewriteRule pattern or there will not be a 2nd variable ie `$2`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^dir/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /dir/index.php?month=$1&day=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Well you could accept my answer since it lead to you solving your issue.